# Structure use in a function C++

Tags: c++, data-structures

I want to create a function that returns a structure, then run a loop for that function. The idea is basically to calculate the maximum sum, start point and end point of a set of n numbers (1000 in this case) and this for 10 lines in a text file

```
struct triple
{
    float Max;
    int sp;
    int ep;
};

triple Max_line(string linename, int n)
{
    int k, i, stp, enp, j;
    triple Result;
    float Maxi;
    float T[n];
    string s;
    stringstream ss(linename);
    j = 0;
    Maxi = 0;
    stp = 0;
    enp = 0;
    while (getline(ss, s, ',')and k < n)
    {
        T[j] = atof(s.c_str());
        j++;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        int k;
        float S;
        S = T[i];
        k = i;
        while (k < n - 1)
        {
            S = S + T[k + 1];
            if (S > Maxi)
            {
                Maxi = S;
                stp = i + 1;
                enp = k + 2;
            }
            k++;
        }
    }


    Result = { Maxi, stp, enp }
    return Result;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int i, j;
    triple fin;
    fstream myfile("1000.txt"); //extract data from a file containing 10 lines each has 1000 different numbers
    string a, b;
    getline(myfile, a); //skip the first line 
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        getline(myfile, b);
        fin = Max_line(b, 1000);
        cout << fin.Max << ";" << fin.sp << ";" << fin.ep << endl;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I printed the results inside the Max_line function it gave me the right values, I don't understand why it's not working inside the for loop.
Can anyone help me with that please?

Comment: I think your `TAB` key appears to be stuck.

Comment: I get errors trying to compile that.

Comment: `Result = { Maxi, stp, enp }` you have a missing semi-colon at the end of that line.

Comment: `float T[n]` is not valid C++ (unless `n` is a compile-time constant, which it isn't here).